# Call to action: Fight spam

Tags: discussion, spam

From time in time, *Drupal Answers* gets a bunch of spam posts; sometimes the posts are just one to two in a week, and sometimes there is more spam in a single day.

We have the way to fight that by using the review pages that every user can access. The [first answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers?s=1&pagesize=50&filter=week) tab is useful in this case, as the spammers create a new account every time, and they use answers to spam. Also the [low quality posts](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts?s=1&pagesize=50&filter=week) tab can be useful, as most of the spam posts are catched by the low quality filter.

Lately, the spammers are getting a little smarter, and they post something that is similar to the following:

> drupal needs a title in every content type - every database designer would insist on a **car dvd** or maybe a random integer to identify a content type, but of course it always would be a crazy idea to force people to use a field that may not be needed - not so in Drupal world!

It seems a normal post, except that it is a copy of another post written by another user, where some words are replaced with a spam link.

> drupal needs a title in every content type - every database designer would insist on a **UID** or maybe a random integer to identify a content type, but of course it always would be a crazy idea to force people to use a field that may not be needed - not so in Drupal world!

As you see, *UID* is replaced from *car dvd*, which is a spam link.

Why is it necessary to flag spam? Because when six users flag a post as spam, the post is automatically deleted without the intervention of moderators, which would have more time to resolve other issues. Even before the spam posts get flagged six time, the spam posts get a down-vote for every flag as spam, which take them to the bottom of the answers given for a question, and users can read all the real answers without to read spam posts too.
Moderators depend on you to find spam. When you see spam posts, flag them as you see them.

**TL;DR:** Help us making *Drupal Answers* a better place: Fight spam using the [low quality posts](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts?s=1&pagesize=50&filter=week) and the [first answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers?s=1&pagesize=50&filter=week) tab of the review page. The links I provided here shows the post for all the week; in this way, there is no need to check those pages all the days. You can also select the "month" tab, and see the monthly posts.