# spam flagging workflow too complicated?

Tags: feature-request, spam

This morning there were at least 6 questions along the lines of "Watch Northern Ireland vs Russia Live football Online TV Link". I wanted to follow the [call to action](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/601/call-to-action-fight-spam) and i have a feeling the workflow requires slightly too many clicks - it would be nice to make it faster to flag spam.
Indeed i dont even know if drupal meta is the right place to ask such functionality related stuff ?

Comment: It takes 3 clicks from start to finish to report a post as spam, which can't take more than a couple of seconds - how would you suggest that could be improved? Meta is definitely the right place to ask this kind of question by the way :)

Comment: well ... i was holding a crying baby in my arm and thiought i would do at least something to calm me :) and in that moment, 3 clicks for some @%& spammers felt a little too much. Especially because the second click requires accurate pointing, it felt rather annoying. Since there seems to be more and more spam, it should probably be easier to deal with it.

Comment: Ouch, yeah crying babys will definitely make spammers harder to take ;) You make a very good point, if you have any ideas on how the interface could be changed to facilitate that then I'm sure the devs would take it into consideration (they're a good bunch). I'm struggling to think of a way myself but we there are a lot of creative people on this site so hopefully someone will have an idea or two

Comment: The only way to reduce the number of clicks would be to have a link to mark a post as spam. If a confirmation dialog is shown, the number of clicks is reduced to two; without confirmation dialog, the number of clicks is reduced to one. Clearly, a confirmation dialog is necessary to avoid somebody clicks on the "spam" link inadvertently.

Comment: It might also make it more apparent to newer users that spam flagging is available. I have seen a number of spam posts showing -6, -7 ... which means some are down voting rather than flagging. I would opt for a separate 'Flag as Spam' button with confirmation.